# How to see Cloud SQL Admin API's logs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Since 15/10 I notice a sudden spike on Cloud SQL Admin API queries, but we didn't make any changes in our application or in our environment.

[image]

Is there any place where I can see which queries are these?

In Stackdriver I just found Cloud SQL's logs, but nothing about Cloud SQL Admin API.

---

UPDATE:

According to this https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy 
" While the proxy is running, it makes two calls to the API per hour per connected instance."

And all requests would be registered as '[USER_NAME]'@'cloudsqlproxy~%'

My application uses 5 PODs of sqlproxy on top, nothing that justifies this spike.

In contact with Google Cloud Support, the agent wasn't able to inform me of the origin of this queries as well.

When the volume of Cloud SQL Admin API's queries increase, the connection latency increases up to 5 seconds and my production application gets unusable.

I'm very disappointed with Google Cloud Support, and I'm thinking in move on to another provider.

Comment: Are you using the Cloud SQL proxy by any chance? It uses the Admin API.

Comment: Yes, @Vadim I'm using Cloud SQL proxy, but before 15/10 (begin of spike) the volume of Cloud SQL Admin API's queries didn't increase independently of traffic in our application.

We did a test on the 17th moving the application to Compute Engine (don't using the cloud sql proxy) and even so it had these tremendous spikes on Admin API.

Comment: The Admin API is not used internally by Cloud SQL, it's only used by external clients like gcloud and other applications calling the API, like the Cloud SQL Proxy or user scripts. You should be able to see some information about the usage by going to Cloud Logging and looking at the "audit log" under Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Vadim, but I can't find this amount of queries on logs register.

Comment: Hey @HudsonKanizawa thanks for the followup in the question.  You should definately add that as an answer to this question, and accept the answer.  See [the self-answer documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)